# don't send data at json to restapi in woocommerce

Tags: php, json, api, rest

why don't send data at api to restapi?
this is my code

```
<?php
function getJsonFromUrl(){
    $url = 'https://*******/api/*********';

// Create a new cURL resource
    $ch = curl_init($url);

// Setup request to send json via POST
    $data = array(
        'codem' => '1002'/*,
     'X' => '8',
     'Y' => '7'*/
    );
    $payload = json_encode($data);

// Attach encoded JSON string to the POST fields
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);

// Set the content type to application/json
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json'));

// Return response instead of outputting
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// Execute the POST request
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

// Close cURL resource
    curl_close($ch);

    $resArr = json_decode($result);
    return $resArr;
}
echo "<pre>"; print_r(getJsonFromUrl()); echo "</pre>";

foreach (getJsonFromUrl() as &$value) {
    echo "<br>";
   // echo $value->Codek;
   // echo "<br>";
   // echo $value->Namek;
   // echo "<br>";
}

/* set woo api */
    $autoloader = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/vendor/autoload.php';
    if ( is_readable( $autoloader ) ) {
        require_once $autoloader;
    }
    
    use Automattic\WooCommerce\Client;
    // use Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient\HttpClientException;
    
    function getWoocommerceConfig() {
        $woocommerce = new Client(
            'https://*****.com',
            '*******',
            '*******',
            [
                'wp_api' => true,
                'version' => 'wc/v3',
                'query_string_auth' => true
            ]
        );
      //  return $woocommerce;
    }
       $woocommerce = getWoocommerceConfig();
       $products = getJsonFromUrl();
       $imgCounter = 0;
    
    
    foreach ($products as &$value) {
        $idproduct = $value->Codek;
       // $woocommerce->post('products', $finalproduct);
        if (!$ProductExsit['exist']) {
            /* Create Products */
            $data = array(
                'id' => $value->Codek,
                'name' => $value->Namek,
                'type' => $value->vahedk,
                'sku' => $value->Codek,
                'regular_price' => $value->price_sale1,
    
                'images' => [
                    [
                        'src' => $value->url_pic
                    ]
                ]
            );
            echo '<pre>';print_r($data);echo '</pre>';
            $c = true;
            var_dump($woocommerce,$c);
            /* $productResult = */
            /* wp_insert_post($data); */
            $woocommerce->post('products', $data); //not working
            echo 'Hello';
        } else {
            /* Update product informtion if exist products */
            $data = array(
                'name' => $value->Namek,
                'sku' => $value->Codek,
                'stock_quantity' => $value->stock_quantity,
                'regular_price' => $value->price_sale1,
            );
            $idproduct = $value->Codek;
            $woocommerce->put('products/ . $idproduct, $data');
    
        }
    }
    
    function prepareInitialConfig()
    {
        echo ('Importing data, Wait...')."\n";
        createProducts();
        echo ('Success Mr.Sedaghat! Good Luck!');
    }
    
    prepareInitiaConfig();
    
    /* update products */
    $data = [
        'name' => ['Namek'],
        'sku' => ['Codek'],
        'stock_quantity' => ['stock_quantity'],
        'regular_price' => ['price_sale1'],
    ];
    
    print_r($woocommerce->put('products/[id]', $data));
    
    ?>
```

........................................................................
........................................................................
........................................................................
........................................................................

Comment: Try adding `curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );` before the line `curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload );`.

Comment: not worked.. :(

Comment: Why did you comment out the line `return $woocommerce;` in the `getWoocommerceConfig` function? Could you indicate precisely where you encounter an error? The more details you provide, the more likely you are to get a response. It also reports any errors.